# How to record from an aggregate device, stream to output, and save to file?

Tags: audio, streaming, vlc, audio-recording, macos-sierra

I'm looking for a free macOs Sierra application that supports at the same time:

- Multiple Inputs or Aggregate Device recording
- Streaming to a selected output (And not the default one)
- Saving the recordings to a *.mp3 file

Hope some of you have ideas, Google ran out of it...
I tried VLC but couldn't manage multiple inputs and aggregate devices.
I tried Quicktime but you can't select another output.
Looked for GarageBand but I discovered you have to pay for it now.

Thanks for your help.

`MacBook Air running latest macOs Sierra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/
It allows you to use your mac's sound output as an input. Works perfectly if combined with GarageBand.